# Deploy SqlLocalDB.msi with wix

Tags: deployment, wix, localdb

I want to use SqlLocalDB for my application. The application is deployed with WiX. Now, I am searching a way to install SqlLocalDB when my application is installed for the first time. How can I do that? Would it be enough to deploy some binaries with my application or do I have to install the whole SqlLocalDB.msi? - When installing of the whole msi is needed - how can I do this with WiX? - The goal is, that the result is a single msi-file which holds all what is needed for installing my application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not aware of a private deployment model for LocalDB.  If WiX is your tool of choice, you'll need to use it's Burn bootstrapper feature to install LocalDB as a prerequisite.  The result will be a single EXE that installs 2 MSI's.